# 'Configured for iOS SSO' disabled?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

On the Facebook counterpart of a native iOS app: what's the worst that can happen if you leave the 'Configured for iOS SSO' disabled in the https://developers.facebook.com/apps > basic app settings? I do have this configured in my actual native iOS app, and sharing in Facebook seems to be working alright.

I noticed that if you enable this, the search in your Facebook App links straight to your native app, and I don't want that. I want the search to lead to the app's Facebook profile page – people don't use Facebook App to find their native apps, they use it to find stuff on Facebook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because they changed the behaviour a week ago. You can [read the details here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/604/).

Comment: Ok, thanks. This does make sense on the main site, with canvas apps – what I'm still not getting is, who would want that behavior on iPhone's Facebook App -> the search leads straight to your native app, already installed on your phone, which makes 'liking' the profile page very difficult, even if you wanted to do so.